# JSON valid keys present

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I would know, why **JSON encoded** data (from MongoDB via PHP) presented as:

```
{
    "53a6e02221360e263e000000": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "53a6e02221360e263e000000"
        },
        "title": "1"
    },
    "53a6e02221360e263e000001": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "53a6e02221360e263e000001"
        },
        "title": "2"
    }
}
```

is bad, but:

```
[
    {
        "id": "53a6e02221360e263e000000",
        "title": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "53a6e02221360e263e000001",
        "title": "2"
    }
]
```

is good?
Is any idea? Both valid JSON.

PHP code example:

```
// MongoDB init before it
$cursor = $mongo->db->collection->find();
// For not large data
$result = iterator_to_array( $cursor );
$json = json_encode($result);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is bad"? What error are you getting?

Comment: @wavemode  this means key clearly not represent target field.
For example {{'00001':'tst1'},{'00002':'tst2'}}, via [{'id':'00001', 'title':'tst1'},{'id':'00002','title':'tst2'}]

Comment: I think we still don't understand what your question is about. What do you mean by bad? It doesn't work to insert it? It's bad practice to use that JSON form?

Comment: @wdberkeley Yes, is it bad practice to use that JSON form?

Comment: Yes. Data-as-keys is a bad form as it will severely hinder your ability to perform CRUD operations and aggregation if you don't know the names of the keys that you want to operate on.